# Como generar PDFs con Javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-apps-script

Tengo un programa en Python que lee un archivo de texto (.txt) y con una serie de datos del archivo, genera un PDF con cierta información. 
Para leer el .txt utiliza expresiones regulares. En Javascript no hay problema, lo puedo hacer de forma similar a Python, pero no encuentro ninguna librería que genere un PDF para que pueda se descargado por el usuario de la web.

Alguien sabe si hay alguna librería en Javascript para generar un PDF descargable.

Comment: Creo que la libreria más extendida para este tipo de cosas es [Phantom JS](http://phantomjs.org). Podrías probar, en Python yo uso `pdfkit`

Comment: Eso quieres para en el navegador, o node.js? Si en el navegador, sera suficiente imprimer el documento, y dejar la conversion al usuario?

Comment: Hace ya tiempo que se respondió esta pregunta pero como no se aceptó la respuesta entiendo que dio algún problema la solución. Has probado con Google Apps Script para generar un pdf directamente en tu drive ? No requiere librerías y a veces tener un histórico de los pdfs generados va bien. Aquí te dejo un [link](http://googleappscriptsweb.blogspot.com.es/2015/11/como-crear-pdfs-con-google-apps-script.html) que explica como generar pdf con google apps script. Ya dirás algo.

Comment: PDFMake es una buena librería para crear pdf desde JS, es sencilla y tiene buena documentación. Acá la pagina del proyecto http://pdfmake.org/ y la documentación http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En SOen me he encontrado con esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742271/generating-pdf-files-with-javascript) muy similar a la tuya, en ella se menciona la librería [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), no la he probado aún, pero promete entregarte archivos PDF con un código tan simple como este:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world.');
doc.save('Test.pdf');
```

Espero te haya servido y bienvenido a SOes.

Comment: Vaya, es obvio que todavía estoy muy centrado en Python y no entiendo el proceso de importar librerías. Tendré que empezar por ahí. Gracias de todos modos.