# Leer Word y Generar un PDF con PHP

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word

estoy usando la libreria `PHPWord` para abrir una plantilla de Word tiene algunos datos que se generar dinamicamente y dan como resultado un Word que descarga el usuario, mi pregunta seria ¿Se puede que en lugar de que mande un Word mande un PDF de la plantilla generada? Y si se puede ¿Cómo seria?

Este es el codigo que utilizo para lanzar la descarga del Word.

Gracias.

```
 $filedescargar = "Contrato.docx";
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8');
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$filedescargar."; charset=utf-8");
 header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
 header('Expires: 0');
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
 header('Pragma: public');
 header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filedescargar));

 readfile($filename);
```

Comment: [Aquí puedes encontrar](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/311) algunos ejemplos de código.

Answer (score 1):

Para un caso similar lo que yo hice fue generar el archivo Word y luego convertirlo a PDF, te comparto lo que hice para poder hacer la conversión:

1. Instalar las librerías de libreoffice (esto es para una mac pero puedes bajarlo para cualquier SO):

http://mirrors.adams.edu/LibreOffice/mac/LibreOffice_4.3.7_MacOS_x86-64.dmg

2. Instalar la herramienta unoconv (esto lo corrí en una mac pero puedes instalarlo en cualquier SO):

   brew install unoconv --HEAD
3. Instalar y usar la librería PHP-unoconv para hacer la conversión:

https://github.com/alchemy-fr/PHP-Unoconv

Comment: ¿Tendras un ejemplo de su implementación una vez que esta instalado? Gracias.

Comment: Para usar la librería PHP-unoconv:
`$unoconv = Unoconv::create();`
`$unoconv->transcode($originFile, 'pdf', $outputFile);`

Comment: Puedes ver también las respuestas de otra pregunta similar:
https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325/como-generar-pdfs-con-javascript